# modal elements is not able to find through selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

If I click one button, It will open the modal and there I have to fill the form and click on submit button.
am able to fill the form till those fields which are visible by default in the modal.
But not able to fill the other fields which are visible only after the scroll down.

Is there any solution for the above problem.
for those element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to answer of @Shoaib Akhtar you can use `JavascriptExecutor` to scroll to element

```
// Create instance of Javascript executor

JavascriptExecutor je = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

//Identify the WebElement which will appear after scrolling down

WebElement element = driver.findElement("Locator");

// now execute query which actually will scroll until that element is not appeared on page.

je.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);",element);

//and then code for operations
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to scroll down to element first and then perform an action like sendKeys. You need also need to apply wait.

You can use the `org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions` class to move to an element:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("my-id"));
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(element);
actions.perform();
```

For Scroll down without an element:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;

jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,250)", "");
```

OR

```
jse.executeScript("scroll(0,250)");
```

Try below code :-

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("javascript:window.scrollBy(250, 350)");
```

Try Sankalp code it will work

full code example be like :-

```
driver.get("https://jquery.com/");

try {
    Thread.sleep(6000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"legal\"]/ul/li[1]/a"));
js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);",element);
System.out.println("Done");
```

Comment: hi sir,i tried to scroll by using above code but it is not scrolling

Answer (score 0):

You need to first scroll in order to make those element appear, after that write the remaining code

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("scroll(0,400)");//This  will scroll page 400 pixel vertical
```